# Python script to substitute text in HTML file with user-supplied values

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, substitution

I have an hmtl file that looks like:

```
...
<!-- Special_ID -->
<p> stuff1 </p>
<p> stuff2 </p>
<!-- /Special_ID -->
...
```

I have an INI file:

```
[general]
param=stuff1
 stuff2
```

If the user edits the file and changes the `param` value to `test`, I want the html file to be changed to:

```
...
<!-- Special_ID -->
<p> test </p>
<!-- /Special_ID -->
...
```

Currently, what I'm doing is parsing the INI file (Python's `ConfigParser`) and then turning the section ("general") and option ("param") into a start and stop special id like in the examples above.

Then:

```
while we haven't found the start id:
    just write a line to some temporary file

write our start id to the temp file
write out new value ("test") to the temp file # surround with <p>

loop through original file until we find the stop id
then write the stop id and the rest of the file to temp

replace original file with tmp file
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Perhaps a Python module that already does this.

I also don't particularly like requiring the `<!-- Special_ID -->`, but I'm not using a web framework (just a simple app), so I can't just do a fancy `<p py:for ...>...` like in TurboGears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall not sure about the current approach you've presented, but here is how you can replace all the `p` elements after a specific comment and insert a new `p` element instead (using `BeautifulSoup` HTML parser). The idea is to:

- find the comment in the HTML
- loop through all the `p` [sibling elements](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)
- remove every `p` element found with [`.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)
- use [`.insert_after()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) to insert a new `p` element after the comment

The working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

data = """
<!-- Special_ID -->
<p> stuff1 </p>
<p> stuff2 </p>
<!-- /Special_ID -->
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

# find "Special_ID" comment
special_id = soup.find(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and "Special_ID" in text)

# find all sibling "p" elements
for p in special_id.find_next_siblings("p"):
    p.extract()

# create new "p" element
tag = soup.new_tag("p")
tag.string = "test"

# insert the new "p" element after the comment
special_id.insert_after(tag)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<!-- Special_ID -->
<p>
 test
</p>
<!-- /Special_ID -->
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a great idea! Also, you implied a good point. If I assume that I will only ever need to replace the sibling p tags, then I don't need a special id comment to close. Instead of removing up to the close comment, remove up through the last p tag.